# Deletion of multiple resources in JAX-RS Service jersey implementation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications, jersey

I am new to restful services and willing to get some ideas from the experts.

The application which will be accessing my service is having a `datatable-grid` (each row of the grid represents an Employee Object/Entity) where user can delete more than 1 records at a time(based on the number of checkbox selected by the user). In such kind of a delete operating how will be the URL representation and how will the data be send to the service?

**My Idea**

Since the number of rows deleted by the differs (based on the number of checkbox selected by the user), hence I am opting for the query string and below will be the URL representation using which I can get the data in my service:

`/deleteEmployees?id=1,2,3`

i.e. a comma seperated values of the id's which will uniquely identify a record in the table.

Based on my Idea, I have a few questions:

1) The query String mentioned above contains of `comma-seperated` values (i.e. Ids). Is it a valid URL where query strings will contain this kind of values?

2) Is there any restrictions in defining the query strings of an URL (like the way I did using csv)?

3) Any other alternative of achieving the same in a better and efficient manner?

P.S. I am new on this and hence looking for different ideas from the experts and try to understand what is correct and what is not.

Comment: I don't think REST really likes deleting whole subset of elements of a resource at a time. If you had to do it this way, CSV is fine in a url. You could also have the CSV as a custom header value in the HTTP request. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) for restrictions. I would instead loop through the checkbox selections and make a DELETE HTTP request on `/employee/{id}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. your alternative of looping through it is also fine. But, isn't it like making the service call n times rather than one at a go? Please comment on this.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. It might just be more REST-like since you are interacting with a resource with HTTP methods (ex: DELETE) instead of with actions like `/deleteEmployees`

Comment: The wiki article for [`REST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) describes how resources should be accessed. Otherwise, you can read the whole [REST Thesis](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm). It's just a feeling I've had while working with RESTful architectures.

Comment: The option with a header might even be better. If you're accessing the whole set of `Employee` resources at `/employees`, you can send a DELETE HTTP request, with a header like `Employees-To-Delete: 1,2,3`. That seems more REST-like to me.

Comment: Thanks for the response...I will wait for some other experts to comment on this as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comma separated list of Employee ids is a fine way to do it, but I wouldn't put it in a URL with an action in it, ie. `/deleteEmployees?id=1,2,3`. REST is more about identifying resources, rather than actions, in URLs. I would either loop through each one of the employee ids to delete and send an HTTP DELETE request for each

```
DELETE /employees/1 HTTP/1.1
DELETE /employees/2 HTTP/1.1
DELETE /employees/3 HTTP/1.1
```

Another alternative is to send one HTTP DELETE request to a URL like `/employees`, keeping the suggested REST identification of resources and using HTTP methods. You would pass the list of ids in an HTTP header.

```
DELETE /employees HTTP/1.1
Employees-To-Delete: 1,2,3
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid) for character restrictions in URLs.